# Problem with CSS transitions on a tags in Safari

Tags: html, css, webkit, webkit-transition

I'm having trouble with a `-webkit-transition` effect in a HTML page. The page is here:

http://www.newerawrestling.co.uk/new/

Basically, the colour of the links within the main sections (marked up in a `<section>` tag respectively) seem to be broken. They should be an off-white (#F5F5F5) and transition to a gold (#FFCC00) on hover, but they display as grey and flicker between both white and gold on hover but don't act as they should.

I've validated both the HTML and the CSS; the HTML passed with the CSS failed for containing CSS3 selectors and declarations (as far as could see) and I've inspected the links using Chrome's Web Inspector, but couldn't see any conflicting rules.

Has any one had this problem, or able to see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Are you talking about the link "Return to shop home"? I’m on Chrome 15 OS X and it looks good to me: it’s off white and fades smoothly to gold on hover (and smoothly back on mouse out).

Comment: Yeah, as per my answer it was when it became a "visited" link the buggy-ness started, but it's all fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crap. As if by sod's law, I've just spotted the mistake after posting this question: I had a rule:

```
footer a:link, a:visited {
    color: #999;
}
```

D'oh!